# Increase width of seach textbox inside navbar-header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search textbox in navbar-header, on collapse, the width of the textbox is fine. But in full screen, the textbox width is reduced. How can I increase the width in full screen mode?

I know there are a lot of questions, like this on SO and the web.

However, I have tried all the suggestions, none has helped me.

here is my code, can  someone tell what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

```css
.navbar .navbar-form {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  background: #465f62;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-area">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Colony</a>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-area">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="nbAcctDD" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Hello Doe <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Log Out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is preferred that you give us `clean` code. By clean I mean include the closest version to the original bootstrap code plus your modifications, not one where you have "tried everything" and left every failed attempt in the code. This makes solving your problem more difficult since we actually have to solve a number of issues just to return to the base state of your code. If you could provide that, I'd gladly look at your problem again :)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but I started from this bootstrap example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I was referring to some `div class="col-md...` stuff that did nothing, in addition to the user name at the top right of the navbar. Anyways, I'll take a look at the bootstrap example and try and find a working solution from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/temupa/3/edit?html,output)

Because bootstrap(BT) just use the default **input width** to achieve the navbar input. So if you want to redefine the width of input, maybe **jquery** is a better choice.

```
$(window).resize(function (){
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('input').width(width - 380);
})
```

the number `380` is from of the **colony** and **Hello Doe** width. After all, there is enough space to arrangement all elements.

Comment: This answer worked on large screen however when you entered mobile-view the search bar would be half of the intended width. I've suggested an edit that fixes this.